# can't send messages over websocket with pusher and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pusher

I tried to send some Test-Data to my WebsocketServer, but I can't get it work :(

my FireBug Console says this:

```
Pusher : State changed : initialized -> connecting
Pusher : Connecting : ws://192.168.56.101:8080/app/123?protocol=5&client=js&version=1.12.5&flash=false
Pusher : State changed : connecting -> connected
Pusher : Event sent : {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"channel":"test"}}
Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","data":{},"channel":"test"}
Pusher : No callbacks on test for pusher:subscription_succeeded
```

my Controller looks like this:

```
Pusher.trigger('test', 'my_event', {:message => 'hello world'})
```

my developement.rb like this:

```
  # Pusher settings
  require 'pusher'
  Pusher.app_id = '123'
  Pusher.key = '123'
  Pusher.secret = '123'
  Pusher.host = 'localhost'
  Pusher.logger = Rails.logger
```

my developement.log has this entrys:
with Pusher.localhost i get this error:

```
Pusher::Error (404 Not found (/apps/123/events)):
  app/controllers/admin/broadcasts_controller.rb:17:in `create'
```

without Pusher.host i got this:

```
   Pusher::AuthenticationError (Unknown auth_key):
      app/controllers/home_controller.rb:3:in `index'
```

Comment: Do you have a Pusher account? The client is trying to connect to `ws://192.168.56.101:8080` and the Pusher setting you have aren't valid Pusher credentials.

Comment: @leggetter I use a local websocket server ( slanger) with my php project the settings works

Comment: Definitely worth *highlighting* that this is Slanger. Without specifying *host* you'll be hitting the real Pusher service where those credentials definitely won't be valid. What port is the Slanger REST/Web API listening on? Do you need to configure that as well as the host?

Comment: Slanger is listening on 4567. When I set it up with ```Puser.host = '192.168.56.101'``` and ```Pusher.port = '4567'``` I ot this error: ```bad component(expected port component): 4567```

Comment: remove quote from ( Pusher.port = 4567 )